# passing json with jquery

Tags: jquery, .post

I have a working jquery program which talks to a php program on a server and am moving json data from php to the front end is no issue.

Now I need to send json data to my backend php server

When I use this syntax

```
  '$.post("../wrk/filterquest.php",{
    "yesTransactionId" : "yesTransactionId",  
    "oproductOfferId" : "productOfferId"
    },
    function ...'
```

My php receives it. I check by listing a test file the php builds

```
machinechek@machinechek.com [~/public_html/wrk]# cat test
filterquestPOST=array (
yesTransactionId => yesTransactionId,
oproductOfferId => productOfferId,
)
GET=array (
)
```

however when I declare a string and manually load the same json into it

```
'poststr = " {\"yesTransactionId\" : \"yesTransactionId\", \"oproductOfferId\" : \"productOfferId\"}";'
```

I and try to send it

```
$.post("../wrk/filterquest.php",poststr,
 function...
```

My php does NOT get it

```
machinechek@machinechek.com [~/public_html/wrk]# cat test
filterquestPOST=array (
)
GET=array (
)
```

If you care the php that writes the test file I use to trace looks like

```
'<?php

 try
 {

 // Debug
 $debu = "> test";
 exec( $debu);
 $lang_str = var_export($_POST,true);
 $debu = "echo 'filterquestPOST=". $lang_str ."' >test";
 exec( $debu);
 $lang_str = var_export($_GET,true);
 $debu = "echo 'GET=". $lang_str ."' >>test";
 exec( $debu);
 //Open database connection ....'
```

So what is the syntax I need to place json in a string and get that string variable to to the backend server?  (Note I can build a javascript array and use JSON.stringify to load a multilevel string. But I can not even get this simple string to move.

Thanks

Comment: json being passed is not a string, but poststr is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The basic array I am trying to pass is stored in c_char_val.

I had thought I had to move it to a string and did that with this command

```
var poststr = JSON.stringify(c_char_val);
```

However I found a thread that said I do NOT need to do that.

Instead I used this syntax which WORKS

```
 $.post("../wrk/filterquest.php",{myData:c_char_val},
 function( ...
```

which gave me this result when I checked my backend server

```
machinechek@machinechek.com [~/public_html/wrk]# cat test
filterquestPOST=array (
 myData => 
  array (
   Picked => 
    array (
     0 => 
      array (
       char_id => char11,
       charval_id => 12,
    ),
   ),
  ),
 )
 GET=array (
 )
```